# SSIS run time error occurs when run on SQL Server catalog

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have create a **SSIS package** to extract data from **oracle source** and load data into a **SQL Server** database. It runs successfully when run it on SSIS. 
But I'm getting an error when I runs the packages on SQL Server catalog. 
Errors shown below

[image]

I also changed the execution type into 64 to 32 and try again. But same error occurred. 
Kindly give solution for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using an agent job to trigger the package?

Comment: By "run it on SSIS" do you mean run it in SQL Server Data Tools? Is the SQL Server different to where SQL Server Data Tools is installed? The first obvious problem with Oracle and SSIS is that you need to install the Oracle driver on the SQL Server. Besides that there are many other issues that can occur.

Comment: Hi holder, yes, I have run the package by triggering agent job and as also by catalog. But same error occurs.

Comment: Hi Nick, 
yes I mean SQL Server Data Tool. Both SQL Server and the data tool install in same server and Oracle source is installed in another server. Both servers comes same domain.
I have installed the Oracle client on the sql server.

Comment: Hi Nick, 
yes I mean SQL Server Data Tool. Both SQL Server and the data tool install in same server and Oracle source is installed in another server. Both servers comes same domain.
I have installed the Oracle client on the sql server.
Nick pls tell me what you mean by "Oracle driver" ?
Here I use SQL Server 2017 enterprise and SQL Server Data tool 2015.  
Can you pls list down required drivers?

Comment: You said you're loading from an Oracle source. To do that you need to install some kind of Oracle driver. If you can run it in SSDT then you must've already done that. Not sure where to go from here - it could be many things.

Comment: Hi Nick,
Can you bit explain the reasons for it? I have no idea about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change it to 32bit in the package, and in the SQL Agent job if there is one. Also, as you are using ODBC, ensure you're using the 32bit ODBC driver and not the 64bit version - There are two different ODBC Data Source Administrators, one for each.

You could always change the job to OLE DB and see if that works correct just to make sure it's not a network/firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the issue should be related to account permissions.

> As per my understanding, the account that log on the `SQL Agent job`
>   may doesn’t have permission to access the database server or SSIS
>   engine uses the design time values of a task until it actually runs a
>   task when DelayValidation is not set to true.

Note: **If user has `sysadmin` permission doesn't means he has permissions to access the database server in ODBC Connection Manager.**

Error message Fix:

Make sure the account in the job step is used to run the package has permissions to access the database server in `ODBC Connection Manager`. And change the DelayValidation property of your `Data Flow Task` to true and then `re-ran` the job.

Comment: This is an Oracle connection. Only in very specific situations does Oracle take any notice of the windows user.